# I want to build Xpath for following tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, find

I want to buid Xpath for depart date drop down date field

https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/index.html?int=HOME-BOOKING-WIDGET-ADVANCED-AIR

I have tried so many combinations but its not working.

example -

```
//input[@id='departureDate']/span[@class='swa-icon--icon']
//span[@class='swa-icon--icon']

<div class="flyout-trigger date-input"><div class="input input_icon input_left input_secondary"><input type="text" aria-label="Depart Date in mm/dd/yyyy format, valid dates from Jun 12 2019 to Jan 5 2020. To use a date picker press the down arrow." aria-owns="calendar-14" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="departureDate" spellcheck="false" aria-required="true" class="input--text"><div class="input--icon-separator"><span class="swa-icon input--icon swa-icon_calendar" icon="swa-icon_calendar" size="18" role="presentation" style="font-size: 18px;"><span role="presentation" class="swa-icon--icon"></span></span></div></div></div>

\
```

Comment: Most of these fields have id's so why can't you just add one or use the id '//*[@id="originationAirportCode"]'. I'm assuming this is your site or you have confirmed with them that you can automate the task of booking? [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a link please.

Comment: The DEPART DATE field that triggers the dropdown has an ID, `departureDate`. Is that what you are talking about? A screenshot of that portion of the UI with a circle around the element you are referring to would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is sticking to the value of `aria-label` [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp), you can utilize XPath [`contains()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) in order to locate element basing on the partial text of the aforementioned `aria-label` atrribute, something like:

```
//input[contains(@aria-label,'Depart Date')]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath that you are looking for.

```
 //span[normalize-space(.)='Return date']/following-sibling::div//span[@class='swa-icon--icon']
```

[image]

Comment: Added screenshot which will give more clarity on how the xpath is derived.

Comment: Thank for you response. appreciate your help.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below down vote button. And feel free to upvote.